# Parse.com: PFQueryTableViewController with PFUser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com framework with my iOS app. I want to have two section in an `UITableView`. I read that I can use the `PFQueryTableViewController` to query data from the parse cloud and have it in a `UITableView`. How can I use `PFQueryTableViewController` to query the `User` class `usernames` to be in one section of the `UITableView`, and the `friends` of the `currentUser` to be in the other section of the `UITableView`, `friends` is an array variable that I made every `PFUser` have. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PFQueryTableViewController` class is really intended to be used for a single query only - your requirement needs two queries to be performed (one for the `currentUsers`'s friends, and one for all `User`'s `username`s. If I were you I'd implement my own table view controller that performs the two queries in the background separately, and manages its own calls to `reloadData` when the data is returned from Parse for each section of the `tableView`.